# Cannot connect SAS OnDemand for Academic - SASpy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sas, saspy

I follow the site:

[enter link description here](https://support.sas.com/ondemand/saspy.html)

My `sascfg_personal.py`

```
SAS_config_names=['oda']
oda = {'java' : 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath\\java.exe',
#US Home Region 1
'iomhost' : ['odaws01-usw2.oda.sas.com','odaws02-usw2.oda.sas.com','odaws03-usw2.oda.sas.com','odaws04-usw2.oda.sas.com'],
'iomport' : 8591,
'authkey' : 'oda',
'encoding' : 'utf-8'
}
```

My `_authinfo`

```
oda user q***g@gmail.com password ****
```

When I enter:

```
import saspy
sas = saspy.SASsession()
```

It returns:

```
Using SAS Config named: oda
We failed in getConnection
The application could not log on to the server "odaws04-usw2.oda.sas.com:8591". The load balancing object spawner timed out.

SAS process has terminated unexpectedly. RC from wait was: 4294967290
SAS Connection failed. No connection established. Double check your settings in sascfg_personal.py file.

Attempted to run program C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe with the following parameters:['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath\\java.exe', '-classpath', 'C:\\Users\\PHAN\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\saspyiom.jar;C:\\Users\\PHAN\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\iomclient\\log4j-1.2-api-2.12.4.jar;C:\\Users\\PHAN\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\iomclient\\log4j-api-2.12.4.jar;C:\\Users\\PHAN\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\iomclient\\log4j-core-2.12.4.jar;C:\\Users\\PHAN\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\iomclient\\sas.security.sspi.jar;C:\\Users\\PHAN\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\iomclient\\sas.core.jar;C:\\Users\\PHAN\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\iomclient\\sas.svc.connection.jar;C:\\Users\\PHAN\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\iomclient\\sas.rutil.jar;C:\\Users\\PHAN\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\iomclient\\sas.rutil.nls.jar;C:\\Users\\PHAN\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\iomclient\\sastpj.rutil.jar;C:\\Users\\PHAN\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\thirdparty\\glassfish-corba-internal-api.jar;C:\\Users\\PHAN\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\thirdparty\\glassfish-corba-omgapi.jar;C:\\Users\\PHAN\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\thirdparty\\glassfish-corba-orb.jar;C:\\Users\\PHAN\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\thirdparty\\pfl-basic.jar;C:\\Users\\PHAN\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\thirdparty\\pfl-tf.jar', 'pyiom.saspy2j', '-host', 'localhost', '-stdinport', '64138', '-stdoutport', '64139', '-stderrport', '64140', '-iomhost', 'odaws01-usw2.oda.sas.com;odaws02-usw2.oda.sas.com;odaws03-usw2.oda.sas.com;odaws04-usw2.oda.sas.com', '-iomport', '8591', '-user', 'quocphantruong@gmail.com', '-lrecl', '1048576', '']

No SAS process attached. SAS process has terminated unexpectedly.
Invalid response from SAS on inital submission. printing the SASLOG as diagnostic


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SASIOConnectionError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [17], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 sas = saspy.SASsession()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\saspy\sasbase.py:606, in SASsession.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    603    pass
    605 if failed:
--> 606    raise SASIOConnectionError(res)
    608 if self.pyenc is not None:
    609    if self._io.sascfg.encoding != '':

SASIOConnectionError: Failure establishing SASsession.
 No SAS process attached. SAS process has terminated unexpectedly.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you

Comment: Hi @PTQuoc , were you able to resolve this? I'm facing the same error.

Comment: @AmarpreetSingh: sorry but I am unable to fix that too

Comment: In my case, it was some environment issue, got it resolved. Beware of the environments!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your sascfg_personal.py file in the right directory that is shown by the result the code below.

```
import saspy, os
print(saspy.__file__.replace('__init__.py', 'sascfg_personal.py'))
```